# how to assign xml value to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, xml

how to assign xml value to javascript variable.

data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="webdata.xslt"?>
<information> 
<personal_info> 
<accountname>John Doe</accountname> 
<accountnumber>987654321</accountnumber> 
<mobileuser>Nathan 'Nath' Smith</mobileuser> 
<mobileno>8755559876</mobileno> 
</personal_info> 
</information>
```

mobileno value want to use in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_get.asp
```

The load function:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp
```